# Sails.js search in array

Tags: postgresql, data-structures, model, sails.js, waterline

I'm working with sails and I need to find objects which have a specific value in array.

I've got this model :

```
User = {
 data = { type: 'array}
}
```

When I do that :

```
User.find({data:3}).exec(...) 

// => It's returns nothing
```

And if I try that

```
User.find({data:{contains:3}}).exec(...)

// => It's will return all User who have '3' in the array 
but it will return the users whose have 34 or 13, ... too.
```

There are no solution in sails to find records from an array ?

What's happens if I put the type of data as 'json' ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible actually to search in an `array` or `json` types.

You have to it with associations : http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations

Or get all your users and make the search manually but it's not optimized if you have a lot of users in your database

Comment: Do you know why is not implemented ?

Comment: I don't... I think it's not easily doable cause Waterline support a lot of different database and JSON and Arrays are not real types (as I know) on SQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

It actually IS possible to search array or json types.

What Waterline is doing is the equivalent of `where data = '%3%'`, and in your DB that array is being stored as a string.

You can technically do what you want if you instead

`User.find({data:{contains:',3,'}}).exec(...)`

The above search assumes what you're looking for is not the first/last entry in the array. If there is this possibility, then you would have to do the following to check for all cases.

`{data:{contains:[',3,','[3','3]']}}`

Depending on your App, DB setup this would usually be a very inefficient search. But if is not done often, and the field is indexed, your database is not too big then go for it. I have had to use this method on occasion myself. However you really should check out association's first as mentioned by @jaumard.

Why not implemented yet? Because json objects inside SQL database is relatively new.

Comment: But when the data are [2,3,10]  it can't works right ?

Comment: Ok I will try it ! Thanks !